# How do I call the totalsupply() function in solidity in the same contract?

Tags: solidity

```
uint256 private _tTotal = 100 ether;
uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));

function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
 }

if (totalSupply()<100 && totalSupply()>90){
        //Code here
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a clue about what you are trying to do but from the error you've got, I assume that you need to make your call inside another function exp:

```
function foo() public {
    if (totalSupply()<100){
            //Code here
        }
}
```